# Store in a php array info taking from a line separated by |

Tags: php, arrays

I am reading a txt file on the following way:

```
    $handle = fopen($captionTextFile, "r");
    if ($handle) {
        while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
            echo ($line);
        }
        fclose($handle);
    } 

// Output
IMAG0986.jpg|Title something 1 here|<b>Description</b><br />You can use HTML as you can see!
IMAG0988.jpg|Title something 2 here|<b>Description</b><br />You can use HTML as you can see!
etc...
```

Now I want to store only the values between the first | by line in a php array. Example of what I intend to have:

```
$json = '{"IMAG0986.jpg": "Title something 1 here",
          "IMAG0988.jpg": "Title something 2 here"}';
```

In order to access this array later in this way:

```
$obj = json_decode($json);
print $obj->{'IMAG0986.jpg'}; // print: "Title something 1 here"
```

The problem that I'm having is how do I pass the values from the lines to the array? any help please?

Comment: `fgetcsv()` with `|` and then use `$line[0]` and `$line[1]` or simply `explode()` current `$line`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) to read the file lines to an `array`, then use [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) with `|` delimiter and add the **1st** part as `key` and **2nd** as `value` to an `array`, finally use [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

Something like:

```
<?php
$captionTextFile = "test.pipe";
$arrayFinal = array();
$lines = file($captionTextFile);
foreach($lines as $line) {
    $array = explode("|", $line);
    $arrayFinal[$array[0]] = $array[1];
    }
print_r(json_encode($arrayFinal));
//{"IMAG0986.jpg":"Title something 1 here","IMAG0988.jpg":"Title something 2 here"}

//If you don't need json, just access the array by key:
echo $arrayFinal['IMAG0986.jpg'];
//Title something 1 here
```

---

Answer (score 1):

You can `explode()` the lines into keys and values in an object to achieve that desired JSON result.

```
$data = new stdClass();

$handle = fopen($captionTextFile, "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        $row = explode('|', $line);
        $data->{$row[0]} = row[1];
    }
    fclose($handle);
} 

json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Nice answer, but you could improve it by using `file` instead of `fopen`